# SWT - How to change the size of Text box dynamically

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am trying to create a Simple UI which contains a combo, a text box and a browse button. The combo will be containing two values: *Execution Times* and *Execute with File*.
When the *Execution Times* option is selected, the combo box followed by a text box should be displayed.
[image]

[image]

when the *Execute with File* option is selected, the combo box, a text box, and a browse button should be displayed.

[image]

When I am switching between these options, the widgets are not getting aligned properly. Refer to the below image. The text box size is not getting expanded to the available space.
[image: Image 4]

```java
public class TestUI {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("StackOverflow");
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

        Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

        Combo combo = new Combo(composite, SWT.READ_ONLY);
        String[] input = { "Execution Times", "Execute with File" };
        combo.setItems(input);

        Text loopText = new Text(composite, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
        GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING | GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
        gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
        loopText.setLayoutData(gridData);
        loopText.setEnabled(false);

        Button browseButton = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
        browseButton.setText("Browse...");
        browseButton.setVisible(false);

        combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                String text2 = combo.getText();
                System.out.println(text2);

                if (text2.equals("Execution Times")) {
                    loopText.setEnabled(true);
                    loopText.setText("1");//$NON-NLS-1$
                    GridData gridData1 = new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.TOP, false, false);
                    gridData1.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
                    gridData1.horizontalSpan = 2;
                    loopText.setLayoutData(gridData1);
                    browseButton.setVisible(false);
                    loopText.getParent().layout();
                }
                if (text2.equals("Execute with File")) {
                    GridData gridData1 = new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.TOP, false, false);
                    gridData1.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
                    loopText.setLayoutData(gridData1);
                    gridData.exclude= false;
                    browseButton.setVisible(true);
                    browseButton.setFocus();
                    loopText.setText("");
                    loopText.setEnabled(false);
                    loopText.getParent().layout();
                }
            }

        });

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Please note that using `GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL`, and several others, is [not recommended](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/GridData.html#FILL_HORIZONTAL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, depending on the combo selection, the text field and text field plus button serve different purposes:

- when *Execution Times* is selected, the number of times is to be entered
- otherwise *Execute with File* requires a file name to be entered or browsed for

Therefore, I would use a `Composite` next to the combo widget to hold either a text field to enter a number (or even a `Spinner`) or a text field and button to enter/select a file name.

```java
Composite composite = new Composite( parent, SWT.NONE );
Text executionTimesText = new Text( composite, SWT.BORDER );
composite.setLayout( new StackLayout() );
Composite executionFileComposite = new Composite( composite, SWT.NONE );
// use a GridLayout to position the file name text field and button within the executionFileComposite
combo.addListener( SWT.Selection, event -> {
  StackLayout layout = ( StackLayout )composite.getLayout();
  if( combo.getSelectionIndex() == 0 ) {
    layout.topControl = executionTimesText;
  } else if( combo.getSelectionIndex() == 1 ) {
    layout.topControl = executionFileComposite;
  }
  composite.layout();
}
```

The `StackLayout` allows you to *stack* the different input fields and switch betwen them as needed (i.e. according to the combo's selection).

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you don't need to recreate the `GridData` for the `Text` widget every time. Instead, just modify the original via `gridData.horizontalSpan`, or if in practice you don't have access to the `GridData` instance, you can get at it via `((GridData) gridData.getLayoutData()).horizontalSpan`, etc.

The reason you're seeing the blank space at the bottom of the `Shell` is because you've created a layout with 3 columns, and then added the following:

1. The `Combo`
2. The `Text` (with `horizontalSpan` set to 2, so this uses 2 columns)
3. The `Button`

The `Combo` and the `Text` take up all 3 columns, so a new row is added for the `Button`. Then you call `pack()`, and the preferred size is calculated, which will be for 2 rows, and the first row only sized for 2 widgets.

Instead of calling `pack()` and shrinking the size of the `Shell` down to the preferred size, we can just set a size on the `Shell` via `Shell.setSize(...)`. In general you don't want to mix `setSize(...)` and layouts, but you've tagged your post with "RCP", so your `Shell` will already have a size and you won't be manually calling `pack()` and `open()`.

Full example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(300, 80);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

    Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));
    composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    final Combo combo = new Combo(composite, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    String[] input = {"Execution Times", "Execute with File"};
    combo.setItems(input);

    final Text loopText = new Text(composite, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
    final GridData textGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
    textGridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
    loopText.setLayoutData(textGridData);
    loopText.setEnabled(false);

    final Button browseButton = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
    browseButton.setText("Browse...");
    browseButton.setVisible(false);

    combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            String text2 = combo.getText();
            System.out.println(text2);

            if (text2.equals("Execution Times")) {
                loopText.setEnabled(true);
                loopText.setText("1");

                // Can also do ((GridData) textGridData.getLayoutData())...
                textGridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
                textGridData.horizontalSpan = 2;

                browseButton.setVisible(false);
                loopText.getParent().layout();
            }
            if (text2.equals("Execute with File")) {
                loopText.setEnabled(false);
                loopText.setText("");

                textGridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
                textGridData.horizontalSpan = 1;

                browseButton.setVisible(true);
                browseButton.setFocus();
                loopText.getParent().layout();
            }
        }

    });

    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you are actually creating and opening a new `Shell`, then call `pack()` (to get the preferred size) prior to making the `Text` widget take up two columns:

```java
shell.pack();

// Move these two lines down to the end
textGridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
browseButton.setVisible(false);
shell.layout(true, true);

shell.open();
```

What we've done is add all 3 widgets without adjusting the `horizontalSpan`. Then, call `pack()` to set the size of the `Shell` assuming that all 3 widgets appear in a single row. After calling `pack()`, set the `horizontalSpan` to 2, and hide the `Button`. When the `Shell` is opened, you will see:

[image]

Comment: Your code is fine if we are not adding any further widgets. If we try to add new widgets then we will see a gap (empty space - consumed by browse button when hidden).